# automatically truncated time part from datetime json object

Tags: jquery, json

My Code:

```
                        //console.log(JSON.stringify(data.voucher.validity));
                        var allData = { "id":data.id, 
                                        "user_id": data.customerId, 
                                        "code":data.voucher.code,
                                        "validity":data.voucher.validity
                                      }
                           console.log('all',allData);    
                           console.log(JSON.stringify(allData));       
                        output += '<a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_voucher"  data-all='+JSON.stringify(allData)+' class="btn btn-brand btn-sm btn-icon update-voucher-modal" data-skin="dark" title="{{"Edit this Voucher"|__}}"><i class="la la-pencil"></i></button>';
```

the above two console.log generates the following two lines:

```
all {id: 1, user_id: 1, code: "FEAST50", validity: "2020-11-24 23:59:59"}
 {"id":1,"user_id":1,"code":"FEAST50","validity":"2020-11-24 23:59:59"}
```

but the data attribute is generated as follows:

```
 data-all="{"id":1,"user_id":1,"code":"FEAST50","validity":"2020-11-24"
```

It should look like:

```
data-all="{"id":1,"user_id":1,"code":"FEAST50","validity":"2020-11-24 23:59:59"}"
```

Why 23:59:59"}" is being truncated? Any idea?

Comment: You're missing quotes when you generate the HTML - so jquery has to to its best to handle it.  Try `"data-all=\'' + JSON.stringify(allData) + '\' class..."`

Comment: Alternatively, if possible, add the data to a jquery object directly, eg `var wrapper=$("<div></div");` then `$("<a href...>").appendTo(wrapper).data("all", allData)` - it won't be an HTML string, but it will store the data without needing to use JSON at all.  Depends on your requirement for `output+=html`